# Streaming audio from iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming

Does anybody know of a way to stream audio from a file being played back in an app over the internet in a standardized streaming audio format? That is server up an Audio stream from the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

You need a http server on you device, multiple packet audio files, like:

- `http://your.com/audio1.mp3`
- `http://your.com/audio2.mp3`
- `http://your.com/audio3.mp3`

And `m3u` file that shows the current realtime file... surely with a small delay, try 0.5 sec, the client opens `http://your.com/play.m3u` and plays with `AVPlayer` the stream.  Like that.

Answer (score 0):

In 4.0, just open the .m3u URL with the `AVAudioPlayer`. It was never simpler to stream audio.

Comment: I was not talking about playing a streaming audio file, but serving up an audio stream from the iPhone.

Comment: Have you figured out a solution to this problem?

Comment: If you can send packets to servers, then you can stream audio. Problem? Read about audio streaming, packet sending and compression, about sreaming algorithms and so on.